# Once there is a Closed Date in a column, I need all corresponding account numbers to be transferred or copied to a new table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a query in Microsoft Access that generates a new table that displays all closed requests. There is a column for account numbers, and a column for closed accounts—however, there are multiple rows with the same account number. I used a query criterion on the “closed” column: Is Not Null. This successfully brings over all accounts that are closed because there is a date in the column, but I also need it to bring all the duplicate account numbers that are in different rows but don’t have a closed date.

Table example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t as t2
              where t2.acctnumber = t.acctnumber and
                    t2.closeddate is not null
             );
```

This returns all rows for accounts where at least one row has a non-NULL `closeddate`.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I think this will work, but I'm just having a little trouble deciphering what the number 1 and t and t2 represent?

Comment: `1` is an arbitrary value.  `exists` only cares if a row is returned.  `t2` is a table alias, a very important part of SQL.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it only returned the lines with a closed date. Where should the SQL code go? On a query or on my existing statusCalls table?

Comment: @taleman . . . Something is wrong wth your implementation.  This should be returning all rows for account numbers that have a closed date on any row.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach which is 2 step.  Looking ahead to a structured set of queries; I would make a Closed Accounts query, that is just Acct Number and Closed Date. One would think this is needed repeatedly in reports and such.

Then I would make a Closed Accounts Detail query. Here you join the Closed Accounts query to the table on the Account number. This will return all rows of each account.

You then have 2 query objects in the navigation pane that are reusable individually as needed in reports, etc.

Comment: Hi, I think your suggestion may be easier. However, what should the Closed Accounts Detail query be made up of and how do I join them?

Comment: In q design view, have Detail TBL & Closed query; join on account. Add all Detail fields you need - or just the * , which is all fields and will auto update if you add/delete fields to the Detail TBL design.